# How do I open .icloud files?

Tags: icloud

I'm saving data to iCloud in my app using iCloud Documents capability, however I'm not using the Documents folder, instead I'm hiding my files in another folder i.e. User'siCloudContainer/MyFolder.

I've uploaded some .plist files to this folder but when I receive them using another device they've been given a .icloud extension. What does this mean and how can I get my original .plist files?

EDIT: It seems that these files have been wrapped by NSFileWrapper during cloud synchronisation.

Answer (score 2):

The answer as I have now discovered is that .icloud files are the metadata that precedes the full file being downloaded to a device.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can gather, iCloud Drive doesn't want you to create your own hierarchy & drop files where you like, it appears you're supposed to put them in pre-defined locations...

This was the best layman's explanation I could find as to how it works; I'm not a dev, so the details would need filling in by someone with more knowledge than me.
[iCloud Drive and Document Picker for iOS 8: Explained](http://www.imore.com/icloud-drive-documentpicker-ios-8-explained)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! It seems I need to get used to Apple's new system. I thought it would be much the same as the last.

Comment: I've read this and it doesn't cover what I need.

Comment: NSFileWrapper is way beyond my pay grade, sorry