# .icloud files & (possibly) finding a way to retrieve them?

Tags: icloud

I have a couple of old .icloud files in my Google Drive that I've really been wanting to open up and take a look at. But I can't find a way to open them with any tools or apps. Not even iCloud itself.

I read up and found out that the .icloud file extension is just "the metadata that precedes the full file being downloaded to a device." as quoted from Rob Sanders: [How do I open .icloud files?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/152880/how-do-i-open-icloud-files), However, I never really found the answer as to if I can retrieve the full file back in its proper form or not.

I presume that I won't be able to get the files back, since there's nothing in my iCloud Drive storage (I emptied it a while back), and since it most likely needs some sort of peer connection; like a .torrent file. If anyone knows a way to retrieve the full file, please let me know. If not, or if there's no way to, then that's fine. I'll live lol. Thanks!

I have a 2016 MacBook Pro, but I also have a gaming PC (that's my daily driver now).

Comment: Have you tried a text editor? Notepad++ (PC) or BBEdit (Mac) should be able to open pretty much any kind of file.